# How to add a "Top happenings/Recent Updates" section to a website built with Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm developing a website with symfony 1.4. The users upload photos and the photos are saved in a database.

Now on the homepage, I have some content and I want to have a section that shows the recently uploaded photos. I'm not sure what is the best way of doing this. Could you please point me in right direction?

The only way I can think of is to have `$sf_content` hold the main content (which will come from the app/modules) and for recent uploads, have `layout.php` do database access+business logic+rendering but that will violate the MVC and will involve huge database access every time the user navigates in the website.

Can it be made better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use components.

**apps/yourapp/modules/yourmodule/actions/components.class.php**

```
class yourmodulenameComponents extends sfComponents {


    public function executeRfoto() {

        $this->photos = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Photo') ->getRecentPhotos();

    }
```

In **model**:

```
public function getRecentPhotos()
  {
    $q = $this->createQuery('a')
              ->addORDERBY('DESC');

    return $q->execute();
  }
```

in your **apps/yourapp/modules/yourmodule/themplates/_rfoto.php**

```
    foreach ($photos as $photo){
// Make some stuff
}
```

And In **layout.php** , or other place where you want to put your photo:

```
   <?php include_component('yourmodule' ,'rfoto')?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but will it reduce the amount of database access?

Comment: I think that this way is symfony way, and in your situation you have very simple query(get 10 or 20 last images form one table), and I think that in your case will not be some critical loads.

Comment: The actual situation is different. Image uploading is just a simpler version of it. So does there happen to be a better way?

Comment: You can also enable APC, you can read about in here [Symfony meets APC (Alternative PHP Cache)](http://www.zalas.eu/symfony-meets-apc-alternative-php-cache).Ho many user per hour in your project?

Comment: not many. 10-20 or so. So I suppose that'll not be a problem. and I'm already using APC.

Comment: 10 - 20 it will be not a problem,and it will be not a problem without APC;-)